# Cannot locate elements in Android Chrome

Tags: android, appium

I'm trying to locate elements in android chrome on www.facebook.com using `UI Automator Viewer` but I **cannot** drill into the browser. I can locate address bar, tabs button, option button but nothing inside the browser like email, password textfield, login button etc.

See the image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the UI Automator Viewer was acting funny. Restart did the trick. 
Everything works fine now

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to identify elements that are within web view thats why uiautomatorviewer will not work.

You have to use chrome remote debugging to identify elements within webview.
Refer this links

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews